# How to use scala.sys.process with scala.js

Tags: scala, scala.js

I have imported `scala.sys.process._` into my scala.js project. That alone doesn't cause any problems, but if I add a simple command such as `println("ls".!!)` I get a gazillion errors, such as

```
[error] Referring to non-existent class java.lang.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.ProcessCreation.apply(scala.collection.Seq,scala.Option,scala.collection.Seq)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.Process$.apply(scala.collection.Seq,scala.Option,scala.collection.Seq)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.ProcessCreation.apply(java.lang.String,scala.Option,scala.collection.Seq)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.Process$.apply(java.lang.String,scala.Option,scala.collection.Seq)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.ProcessCreation.apply(java.lang.String)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.Process$.apply(java.lang.String)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.ProcessImplicits.stringToProcess(java.lang.String)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.package$.stringToProcess(java.lang.String)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from draw.Main$.main(org.scalajs.dom.raw.HTMLCanvasElement)scala.Unit
[error]   called from draw.Main$.$$js$exported$meth$main(org.scalajs.dom.raw.HTMLCanvasElement)java.lang.Object
[error]   called from draw.Main$.main
[error]   exported to JavaScript with @JSExport
[error] involving instantiated classes:
[error]   scala.sys.process.Process$
[error]   scala.sys.process.package$
[error]   draw.Main$
[error] Referring to non-existent class java.io.File
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.ProcessCreation.apply(scala.collection.Seq,scala.Option,scala.collection.Seq)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.Process$.apply(scala.collection.Seq,scala.Option,scala.collection.Seq)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.ProcessCreation.apply(java.lang.String,scala.Option,scala.collection.Seq)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.Process$.apply(java.lang.String,scala.Option,scala.collection.Seq)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.ProcessCreation.apply(java.lang.String)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.Process$.apply(java.lang.String)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.ProcessImplicits.stringToProcess(java.lang.String)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from scala.sys.process.package$.stringToProcess(java.lang.String)scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder
[error]   called from draw.Main$.main(org.scalajs.dom.raw.HTMLCanvasElement)scala.Unit
[error]   called from draw.Main$.$$js$exported$meth$main(org.scalajs.dom.raw.HTMLCanvasElement)java.lang.Object
[error]   called from draw.Main$.main
[error]   exported to JavaScript with @JSExport
[error] involving instantiated classes:
[error]   scala.sys.process.Process$
[error]   scala.sys.process.package$
[error]   draw.Main$
[error] Referring to non-existent method java.lang.ProcessBuilder.environment()java.util.Map
```

Importing extra classes such as java.lang.ProcessBuilder and java.io.File has no impact on the content of these errors. Is there something very simple that I am missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't simply import arbitrary Scala libraries into Scala.js -- while the *language* is the same, the *environment* is very different. Many standard Scala libraries simply don't exist in the SJS world, and many of them *can't*, because of the limitations of the JavaScript environment it runs in. It's syntactically legal, so it will compile, but it can't run before there isn't a Scala.js version of the library.

By and large, you should assume that libraries like this *don't* exist in the SJS world, unless you find that someone has specifically ported it. (I honestly don't know whether someone has ported `scala.sys.process` for Node.js; it doesn't make much sense in the browser environment...)